# How do I connect to my React Native App from Deco IDE?

Tags: react-native, deco

I just downloaded Deco IDE for React Native, and opened the sample project. I hit run to open the iOS simulator (on which I've run projects before using the standard `npm start`), and it appears to open up the project, showing a "Project, created in React Native" splash screen, then the screen goes white (which I assume is the first scene, or the transition to it), and then I get this error screen:

[image]

The console log in Deco doesn't offer anything helpful, doesn't show any errors or anything.

```
[10:13:23 AM] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[10:13:23 AM] <START> Crawling File System
[Hot Module Replacement] Server listening on /hot

React packager ready.

[10:13:23 AM] <END>   Crawling File System (654ms)
[10:13:23 AM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[10:13:24 AM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (526ms)
[10:13:24 AM] <START> Building in-memory fs for Assets
[10:13:24 AM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for Assets (326ms)
[10:13:24 AM] <START> Building Haste Map
[10:13:24 AM] <START> Building (deprecated) Asset Map
[10:13:25 AM] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (108ms)
[10:13:25 AM] <END>   Building Haste Map (383ms)
[10:13:25 AM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (1932ms)
```

Can anyone help with this? Deco seems great but I can't get it to work!

NOTE: I've noticed that it looks like Deco is actually installing the App on my simulator, there is a home screen icon for "Project". This is of course different from when I usually run my projects from VS Code and open them in Expo. I'm not clear on how this difference works. (But I imagine it's where my problem lies!)

Comment: With Deco, you aren't using Expo, right?

Comment: I suppose not, as I realized since I wrote the note at the end of my post. So, what do I do then?